# Карты навигации в программе

Tags: гис, карты

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы использования ГИС-систем (навигация по городу, например от точки А до точки Б) для десктопного приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно взять

[вот отсюда](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

карту нужно местности в каком-нибудь svg или в другом формате, вообще народ как-то и карты гугла использует, я точно не помню как но можно, если интересно могу поискать.

Comment: О да мне это очень нужно, буду благодарен

Comment: Вы всё-таки посмотрите Openstreetmap.org - это хорошая штука и с лицензией всё хорошо, а у гугла не факт, что просто так можно использовать. вот ещё один сайт, где много полезной информации http://gis-lab.info/